# use python regex to find key=value pairs separated by comma but keep quoted portion together

Tags: python, regex, key

How do you get the key, value pair from following string:

```
s='pairs=<A=name,B=2,C="Last, First">'
```

the part within the brackets < ... > contains K=V pairs, which are separated by commas. The value part could have commas in quotes.

My clunky solution is to get the portion between bracket, find positions of comma that is not in quotes, substring by found comma positions, then split key / value by '=', and turn the whole thing to a dict.

regex should be able to do this in much straightforward way, right?

I got to this far:

```
re.findall('([A-Z]+[0-9]*)=([^,]*)', s)
```

but result did not turn out to be right:

```
[('A', 'name'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '"Last')]
```

How to ignore the commas in the quotes?

### EDIT

I made a mistake. My original regex pattern should not have worked, if the key can have lower case letter.

I took that into consideration, and combined and eph and vks' solutions:

```
s='Pairs=<Aa=name,Bb=2,Cc="Last, First">'
re.findall('([A-Za-z]+[0-9]*)=("[^"]*"|[^,]*)', re.findall(r"<([^>]*)>",s)[0])
```

and it seems to work.

Improvement upon this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.findall('([A-Z]+[0-9]*)=("[^"]*"|[^,]*)', s)
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my question that I ignored fact the key can have lower case as well. I took that into consideration, and combined yours and vks' solutions: re.findall('([A-Za-z]+[0-9]*)=("[^"]*"|[^,]*)', re.findall(r"<([^>]*)>",s)[0]). and it seems to work. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @xyliu00 It depends on more detail.For example, would `s` be `parts1=<...>,parts2=<...>` or `parts=<A="1>2">` or `parts=<A="\"">`?

Comment: only one Parts1=<...> in each line. we can assume < | > | " | = inside the quoted values. But as any file given by other parties, it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @xyliu00 If `"` can be inside the quoted values, there must be some escaping method or ambiguity cound exist.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be to extract all between `<>` and then split by `,` not in `quotes`.

```
s='pairs=<A=name,B=2,C="Last, First">'
print re.split(r',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)',re.findall(r"<([^>]*)>",s)[0])
```

Output:`['A=name', 'B=2', 'C="Last, First"']`

Not you can easily make pairs by splitting on `=`.

```
print map(lambda x:x.split("="),z)
```

Output:`[['A', 'name'], ['B', '2'], ['C', '"Last, First"']]`

Comment: `<([^>]*)>` might not the best choice since it is not clear whether `>` would appear in the value part.

Comment: @eph `the part within the brackets < ... > ` from question

Comment: @vks Thanks! It works cleaner than my original solution. I like eph 's solution too, since it uses straightforward regex pattern matching.

Comment: @xyliu00 your current improved solution has many flaws...the key has the format fixed....the surest way is to do it the right way.....split by `,` and then split by `=`